# converting Html Form data to JSON object using angular JS

Tags: angularjs

Product Id
                            
                                 *</span> -->
                                
                                    Product Id is required.
                                
                            
                            
                            
                                Product Version
                                
                                     * </span> -->
                                    
                                        Product Version is required.

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: There is no question here. @sonu please fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the "Simple form" provided in the documentation itself:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Here, basically this expression `{{user | json}}` converts the ng-Model object user to a json string.
Check out the working example from the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AeIpUEnvuwMGAU0hPzSb?p=preview) provided by them. I have edited the plunk to keep only the part relevant to your query.