# How to upload FormData object using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, form-data

I am new to angular-js, and wants to submit the multipart/form-data with an image and it's $http.post() method supports only json format, so I want to convert formdata object to the json format,

```
$scope.SubmitForm=function()
{
    url = siteurl + '/admin/' + $scope.module + '/add';

    var form=document.getElementById("addForm");
    var formData=new FormData(form);

    $http({
        url     :   url,
        method  :   "POST",
        data    :   formData,
    })
    .then(function(responseText) {                
        alert(JSON.stringify(responseText));

    //process data
    },function(){
        alert("hello from error");
    });

}
```

it didnot work for me; and i tried to make json format data for this and works fine

```
formData={
    "first_name" :  $('#first_name').val(),
    "last_name"  :  $('#last_name'),
    //....
};
```

but don't have any idea to append my image file to this format; what should i do right here to get my job.

Is there any way(function) to convert formdata object to json format

Comment: Converting data [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905608/converting-html-form-data-to-json-object-using-angular-js). But why don't you use ng-model if you are in angular?

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but ng-model will not work for file, and I had new directive to works to but it's cumbersome one,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by putting two line of code like below, in $http configuration lines (thanks every body)-

```
      $http({
            url     :   url,
            method  :   "POST",
            data    :   formData,
            transformRequest: angular.identity, // see the angugular js documentation
            headers : {'Content-Type':undefined}// setting content type to undefined that change the default content type of the angular js
        }).then(function(responseText){
            
            alert(JSON.stringify(responseText));
            ///$scope.tablerows=$scope.totaltablerows;
            ///$scope.searchFunction();
        },function(){
            alert("hello from error");
        });
```

just this works for me

Answer (score 0):

You should really use `ng-model` when working with forms in angular (can you provide your form in your example?). It creates a scope variable to work with in your controller and you will have two way binding if it is already defined... for example as your form isn't present I'd do something like this, this is simplified (and not tested)...:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="SubmitForm()">
    Name: <input ng-model="fields.name">
    Address: <input ng-model="fields.address">
    ....
</form>
```

and in your JS controller...

```
 $scope.submitForm = function(){    
        var data = $scope.fields,
            url = '/admin/' + $scope.module + '/add'; // I assume $scope.module is available from elsewhere...  

        $http.post(url, data).then(function(resp){
        // do stuff...

        });        
    }
```

There's more info here... https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel and W3schools have some examples: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_forms.asp

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.

Answer (score -1):

It Should be constructed like this:

```
  var form = document.getElementById('addForm');
  var fd = new FormData(form);
  var file = this.files[0];    
  fd.append("afile", file);
  // These way you add extra parameters
  fd.append("first_name", $('#first_name').val());
  fd.append("last_name", $('#last_name').val());
```

Reference example - [from github](https://gist.github.com/ebidel/2410898)